# one of my iframes is not working

Tags: iframe

Hi I couldn't understand this. I could view 2 iframes separately but when I put them together into 1 website, I could only see one iframe. Any idea? Thanks. Here's code.

```
<iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="site1.html" scrolling="no" style="height: 480px; border: 0px none; width: 1200px;">
```

Attn: site1(2).html are iframe html too.

Answer (score 2):

You must add **closing tag** for iframe

```
<iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="site1.html" scrolling="no" style="height: 480px; border: 0px none; width: 1200px;"> 
</iframe>

<iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="site1.html" scrolling="no" style="height: 480px; border: 0px none; width: 1200px;"> 
</iframe>
```